# Can't flush dns in kali linux in Virtualbox. It seems like neither of these are my dns client: systemd-resolve, resolvectl, nscd, dnsmasq

Tags: kali-linux, dns, cache

It seems like there are no dns clients(????).... but it's impossibile, it's just  don't know how to find it.

`$ sudo lsof -i :53 -S` does not return anything.

```bash
systemctl restart nscd #or
systemd-resolve --flush-caches #or
resolvectl flush-caches #or
systsemctl restart dnsmasq.service
```

do not succeed, so neither of them are used.
What is my dns client??

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost kali
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver fd0f:ee:b0::1
```

Comment: why would there be a specific DNS client? that's just part of libc functionality.

Comment: @MarcusMüller so I have not a dns client? I don't have any cache?

Comment: you have a DNS client. It's part of your C library; otherwise programs couldn't look up names, could they? I don't know whether glibc on Linux is set up to use some other name resolution cacher through NSS, but it's not unlikely it isn't – after all, Kali is not meant to be an everyday useful operating system, at all, but a one-trick pony for pentesting, where you better think about every DNS request you make, anyways.

Comment: I don't get where this dnsclient in my C library is. I mean, is there a process/thread ? Is it at kernel level?

Comment: no. It's *functionality* in the library. Just like, say the liburl library contains the functionality to do HTTP requests and thus is a HTTP client, the libc library contains the functionality to do DNS requests and hence is a DNS client. When you say `ping example.com`, the `ping` prorgam asks the libc to resolve the name `example.com`, and the libc library does a DNS request.

Comment: @MarcusMüller very very interesting, I never thought about it. so why do I need an "external" dns client at all, like dnsmasq or systemd-resolve ?

Comment: these things serve very different purposes each. You will need to read the documentation for each of them. Sadly nothing I'm willing to explain in a series of comments…